# alternative to `with` block?

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates

I am working at a template system comparable to pug (formerly jade). Templates can contain lines of JavaScript. I solved it using a `with` block:

```jade
- var foo = "bar"  // javascript
p(class=foo)!= bar
```

is compiled to:

```js
function generatedFromString(context) {
    var result = '';
    with (context) {
        var foo = "bar"  // javascript
        result += '<p class="';
        result += escapeHtml(foo);
        result += '">';
        result += bar;
        result += '</p>';
        return result;
    }
}
```

This works great. However, I know that `with` is **deprecated** and it is even **forbidden** in strict mode.

So, my next idea was to copy all values of `context` into `global`. But I suspect this is even worse, since it pollutes the global namespace and slows down the script.

Apart from that, I don't want to get a *ReferenceError* when an undeclared variable is used in a template. So it seems that the only solution is to change the output to

```js
        context.foo = "bar"  // javascript
```

But then I would have to **parse the JavaScript**, which is a lot more effort.

Does anyone know if there is a better solution? Or is it necessary to parse the JavaScript?

Comment: You can set the function's context using something like `call` (eg: `generatedFromString.call(context)`) and use `this.propertyName` to set or access properties.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to use `this` in the template everywhere